# "You did a good job [at/in] answering my questions"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Which phrase is grammatically correct?

> 1. good job *at* answering my questions
> 2. good job *in* answering my questions
> 3. good job answering my questions

Or, are all the phrases correct?

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but *"you did a good job answering my questions"* sounds most fluent, compared to the other choices. Both *"You did a good job in answering ..."* and *You did a good job at answering ..." sound a little awkward, but not totally wrong.

Answer (score 3):

If you write them like this, they're all correct [I turn them into a complete sentences]:

> 1. a. You did a good job **in** answering my question.
>
>    > You can use *in* if you want to say that the thing you did *was* answering my question, and you did it well.
> 2. b. You did a good job **by** answering my question.
>
>    > You can use *by* if you want to say that you did this good job you *because of* or *by* answering my question.
> 3. You are good **at** answering questions.
>
>    > You can only use *at* to describe skill or something someone's good at.